# Bash: two loops inside while loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

As a beginner I'm not sure if this is the best way to do multiple loops!! though it works well, please suggest me if there is an elegant way of doing this (I'm not restricted to bash but I'm not familiar with other languages)

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
            read -n1 -e -p"Top Levels 1-5: " top_levels
            if [ "$top_levels" == "1" ]; then
                echo "top level 1"
            elif [ "$top_levels" == "2" ]; then
                while :; do
                            read -n1 -e -p"Sub Levels 1-5: " sub_levels
                            if [ "$sub_levels" == "1" ]; then
                                echo "sub level 1"
                            elif [ "$sub_levels" == "2" ]; then
                                echo "sub level 2"
                            elif [ "$sub_levels" == "3" ]; then
                                while :; do
                                            read -n1 -e -p"Final Levels 1-5: " final_levels
                                            if [ "$final_levels" == "1" ]; then
                                                echo "Final level 1"
                                            elif [ "$final_levels" == "2" ]; then
                                                echo "Final level 2"
                                            elif [ "$final_levels" == "3" ]; then
                                                echo "Final level 3"
                                            elif [ "$final_levels" == "4" ]; then
                                                echo "Final level 4"
                                            else
                                                echo "bye"
                                                break
                                            fi
                                        done
                            elif [ "$sub_levels" == "4" ]; then
                                echo "sub level 4"
                            else
                                echo "bye"
                                break
                            fi
                        done
            elif [ "$top_levels" == "3" ]; then
                echo "top level 3"
            elif [ "$top_levels" == "4" ]; then
                echo "top level 4"
            else
                echo "bye"
                exit
            fi
        done
```

Comment: More elegant way of doing what? Regardless of the answer, questions asking for improvements to working code probably belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. If a task requires two loops inside another loop - well, there is no more elegant way than putting two loops inside another one. You should describe the desired task: showing the code without explaining what you want to do is not enough for understanding.

Comment: man, you need comments.  It would help people understand what you are doing and why.

Comment: @kuruvi no answer selected :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this

```
#!/bin/bash

process_final_levels() {
    while :; do
        read -n1 -e -p"### Final Levels 1-5: " final_levels
        case $final_levels in
          1) echo "Final level 1";;
          2) echo "Final level 2";;
          3) echo "Final level 3";;
          4) echo "Final level 4";;
          *) echo "returning to sub levels"
            break;;
        esac
    done
}


process_sub_levels() {
    while :; do
        read -n1 -e -p"# Sub Levels 1-5: " sub_levels

        case "$sub_levels" in
          1) echo "sub level 1" ;;
          2) echo "sub level 2" ;;
          3) process_final_levels;;
          4) echo "sub level 4" ;;
          *) echo "returning to top levels"
             break;;
        esac
    done
}


while :; do
    # get top levels to work with
    read -n1 -e -p"Top Levels 1-5: " top_levels

    case "$top_levels" in
      1) echo "top level 1" ;;
      2) process_sub_levels ;;
      3) echo "top level 3" ;;
      4) echo "top level 4" ;;
      *) echo "Bye"
         exit;;
    esac
done
```

I changed the prompt and exiting strings to be more intuitive as to what level you are working on.  I didn't add comments, b/c I have no idea what's this for.  I functionalized, b/c any code that needs to be modified, tested, or maintained should be functionalized.